# Как сконвертировать HTML страницу в PDF по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Хочу сконвертировать `html` страницу в `pdf` средствами `javascript`.
Делаю это используя библиотеки 
по инструкции из видео
Но, получаю в консоли запись:

> html2canvas: Canvas renderer initialized (2543x739 at 0,0) with scale
>   1

и соответственно файл не сохраняется. Можно это как-то поправить или какой-то другой метод использовать?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script>
    function getPDF() {
        html2canvas(document.body,  {
           onrendered: function (canvas) {
              var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
              var doc = new jsPDF({scale: 1});
              doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20,20);
              doc.save('test.pdf');
           }
        });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="javascript:getPDF()">Download PDF</a>

<h1>Example Header</h1>
<input type="text" />
<img src="sp.png" width="371" height="371" />
<input type="submit" value="button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример кода, который делает, что вам надо. Дальше думаю уже доделаете мелочи:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
     <h3>Generate PDF files in client-side JavaScript</h3>

<p>href="https://parall.ax/products/jspdf#"</p>
<p>Or refer to the YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnprxD_sJFE<p>
</div>

<div id="editor"></div>

<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
</body>
<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо за наводку, но он, к сожалению, не сохраняет картинки (canvas) Вот мой пример
http://a-lot-of-money.ru/rasterize
при первом клике рендерится картинка, при втором - скачивается инфа со страницы, но, как видим в файле, - сохраняется только первоначальная текстовая инфа..